# The value of the local variable 'X' is not used, while writing test script in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing test script in selenium using testng annotations. My application has separate fields to upload audios, videos, images etc. I'm using following code to upload images in the respective field.

```
`@Test (priority = 1)   
public void Save() throws InterruptedException
{       
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Add Case"));
Actions action = new Actions (driver);
action.moveToElement(element); 
action.click().build().perform(); //Click on 'Add Case' button 
driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Selenium 7"); 

//upload images
File fisheye_tier1 = new File("*path where images are saved in local machine*");
File[] fisheyeimages = fisheye_tier1.listFiles();
String fishList = "";
for(int i = 0; i < fisheyeimages.length;i++){
fishList += (i != 0 ?"\n":"") + fisheyeimages[i].getAbsolutePath();
}
driver.findElement(By.id("fileupload")).sendKeys(fishList);
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000);`
```

This code works as expected for me and upload all images. But when I use similar concept to upload videos, my test fails. The script to upload videos is as follows:

```
`@Test (priority = 2)
public void Submit() throws InterruptedException
{
//upload videos
File evidence_tier1 = new File("*path where videos are saved in local machine*");
File[] evidenceimages = evidence_tier1.listFiles();
String eviList = "";
for(int i = 0; i < evidenceimages.length;i++){
eviList += (i != 0 ?"\n":"") + evidenceimages[i].getAbsolutePath();
}
driver.findElement(By.id("fileupload1")).sendKeys("eviList");
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

In eclipse it shows a yellow line below `eviList` with error `The value of the local variable eviList is not used`. Seems its a leakage but their is no error when I upload images with same script.

Comment: Did you mean `sendKeys(eviList)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing String "eviList" instead of variable eviList

Update your code as below.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("fileupload1")).sendKeys(eviList);
```

Answer (score 1):

sendKeys("eviList") - you need to pass the variable instead of string - sendKeys(eviList)